# Switch statement in function does not assign variables

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing an HTML page for a class project. It needs to show different information based on what the user has selected. I have 5 buttons at the top with `onclick` that activates a function that *should* be changing the text inside of the `<p>` element below them.

I tried switching `document.GetElementById('main').innerHTML = link;` with `alert('link')`, and it gave me an empty alert box. I've checked my syntax repeatedly, and the case statement has no errors in it. I know that it isn't an error in the button element or the function itself, because it did give me an empty alert box when I tried the `alert` statement I mentioned earlier. So I've ruled out every error I can think of.

Below is the code (with most button elements and case statements removed for brevity)

```
        <script>
            var link = '';

            function TextSwitch(n) {
                switch (n) {
                    case '1':{
                        link = 'Option 1 has been selected'
                        break;
                    }
                }
                document.GetElementById('main').innerHTML = link;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style='background:#ffffee'>
        <div align='center'>
            <button type=button style='width:10%' onclick='TextSwitch(1)'>Option 1</button>
        </div>
        <p id='main'>text
        </p>
```

Comment: `1` and `'1'` are not the same values. The first is a number, the second is a string. `switch` uses strict equality.

Comment: The `{}` after `case` are superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you hade some problems:

- there is not `GetElementById`, it is `getElementById`
- you are trying to compare `1`(number) to `'1'`(string) in your switch statement

you can solve this using 2 cases to the same result on the `switch` or define the proper solution and comparison.

```html
<script>
  var link = '';

  function TextSwitch(n) {
    switch (n) {
      case 1:
      case '1':
        {
          link = 'Option 1 has been selected'
          break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = link;
  }
</script>
</head>

<body style='background:#ffffee'>
  <div align='center'>
    <button type=button style='width:10%' onclick='TextSwitch(1)'>Option 1</button>
  </div>
  <p id='main'>text
  </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that you're passing `1` as a parameter instead of `'1'`.
Your switch is working on strings, and your parameter is an integer. You should change one of them in order to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.toString` within your switch statement (and also remove unnecessary `{}` as mentioned already).

```
function TextSwitch(n) {
    switch (n.toString()) {
        case '1':
            link = 'Option 1 has been selected'
            break;
    }
    document.GetElementById('main').innerHTML = link;
}
```